# ¿Le quedan entradas?

Tags: traducción, gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos

In the question:

```
¿Le quedan entradas?
```

The "pronombre" **le** is it used to express a formal way to ask somebody "*do you have tickets left*"? For example the following question is the equivalent  non-formal way of the same question?

```
¿Te quedan entradas?
```

Comment: Yes. It could also refer to the third person singular. _le quedan entradas a ella?_

Comment: In Spain, **os** is used in both formal and informal: _¿os quedan entradas?_

Comment: *os* is for plural.

Comment: In Spain _os_ would be used for second person singular if you are trying to sound like speaking ancient Castillian ("Ese traje **os** queda muy bien, alteza"; "**Os** chanceáis de mi? Entonces **os** reto a duelo caballero!!").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RAE's entry for [`usted`](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=jDHGqjjQZD6QSpsMYp) is stated that

> Como pronombres de **tercera persona gramatical** a usted y ustedes les corresponden las formas átonas lo(s), la(s) para el complemento directo y **le(s)** para el indirecto

compare their example:

> A ustedes **les** gusta ir a ese baile?

with yours

> (A usted) **le** quedan entradas?

The tricky thing is that `usted/ustedes` is grammatically  considered a third person, even if it refers to a second person (also from the same reference)

> Aunque su referente es siempre una **segunda persona**, pues designa al interlocutor a quien se habla, gramaticalmente es un pronombre de **tercera**

That is why when you are not using the `usted` form you use the pronoun of the second form `te`.